# How to rename a connection created by CMAK?

Tags: windows, vpn

I have a Windows VPN connection that is created by CMAK ([Connection Manager Administration Kit](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/4a602fd8-0e94-45eb-9b8c-4e674187cf70.aspx)). Is there anyway to rename this connection on the client-side, after the installation?

[image]

(For the record I have no idea why Microsoft would lock down the rename function...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of investigation, I got it:

1. Open `%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`. Let's assume the connection's name is "Network A". There sill be a section starting with `[Network A]`. Rename that to, say, `[Network B]`.
2. Go to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Connection Manager\Mappings`. There should be a key called `Network A` as well. Change that to `Network B`.
3. Finally, go to the location pointed in the registry key, and open the .cms file. It should be in the form of `%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\{guid}\{guid}.cms`. Under the `[Connection Manager]` section, change `ServiceName` from `Network A` to `Network B`.
4. Go to Control Panel and open "Change Adapter Settings". If the page is already open, right-click and select "Refresh". The new name should be applied automatically.

Notes:

1. If the message "The service profile is corrupt" appears when trying to connect, some keys / values were not named correctly.
2. To refresh the name of the network shown when clicking the network icon on the taskbar, logout and login again.